# Change date format in array and return a json

Tags: php

How to change date format in my array

`print_r($data);`

```
[01] => Array
    (
        [status] => Pending
        [number] => 123
        [DESCRIPTION] => description
        [STARTDATE] => 1544079879
        [RESTOREDATETIME] => 1544080492
    )
```

I want to change date format

```
$data = $my->getCustFunction();
header("Content-Type: application/json");
print json_encode($data);
return;
```

i wan to return like this

```
[01] => Array
    (
        [status] => Pending
        [number] => 123
        [DESCRIPTION] => description
        [STARTDATE] => 1544079879(d/m/y)
        [RESTOREDATETIME] => 1544080492
    )
```

Comment: you want to return in `d\m\y` format or do you want to concat `(d\m\y)` at the end of the string.

Comment: i wan to convert format

Comment: Can you tell us, just for clarity, what format the date in currently in please.

Comment: it return like this 1544079879. i don't know this

Comment: I would be tempted to do this in the `getCustFunction()` rather than as an after thought

Comment: Just use where you want to show your startDate by echo date('d/M/Y',$data['01']['STARTDATE']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have multiple subarrays:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
   $data[$key]['STARTDATE'] = date('d/m/y',$value['STARTDATE']);
}
```

Comment: Um... `d/m/y` is what the OP wanted

Comment: Try this: `$value['STARTDATE'] = $value['STARTDATE']."(d\m\y)";`

Comment: But this one will generate `01/01/70` which is obviously wrong

Comment: i print data after this but still not convertying itshow this 1544079879

Comment: How would this affect your original array if you didn't pass by reference or use `$data[$key]['STARTDATE'] = ...`

Comment: @dexter This code isn't work properly, `$value['STARTDATE']` would not be changed because you didn't pass by reference. Why are you rejecting suggested edits to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
$data['01']['STARTDATE'] = date("d/m/y", $data['01']['STARTDATE']);
```

**[UPDATE]**
Your array:

```
$data = [
    '01' => [
        'status' => 'Pending',
        'number' => 123,
        'DESCRIPTION' => 'description',
        'STARTDATE' => 1544079879,
        'RESTOREDATETIME' => 1544080492,
    ]
];

print_r($d);
```

*Loop though array items and convert STARTDATE to 'd/m/y' format*

**With 'pass by reference':**

```
foreach ($data as &$item) {
    $item['STARTDATE'] =  date("d/m/y", $item['STARTDATE']);
}
```

Pay attention to '&' in foreach statement, without it you could't change `$item` inside the loop (http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

**With 'classic' style:**

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key]['STARTDATE'] =  date("d/m/y", $value['STARTDATE']);
}
```

**Date formatting parameters:**
According to http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php
   d - Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros
   m - Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros
   y - A two digit representation of a year
   / - separator

Comment: I didn't downvote, but helpful tip: Explain your changes and do not include `<?php ?>`

Comment: Do not use pass by reference if you don't have to. It could be very dangerous for unexperienced PHP developers. Instead use `$data[$key]['STARTDATE'] = ...`

Answer (score 1):

try this

when you get data and before return data, use this code

```
date('d/m/y', 1544079879);
```

to your `STARTDATE` field

Loop below

```
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
   $data[$key]['STARTDATE'] = date('d/m/y',$value['STARTDATE']);
}
```